# MSTest setting Apartment Threading to MTA

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mstest, mta

I'm using MSTest in Visual Studio 2010 on a project that needs the apartment threading model set to MTA.

I've looked online and the items I've found and tried seem to only work with Visual Studio 2008 and 2005, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ploeh/archive/2007/10/21/runningmstestinanmta.aspx.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're right, most of the information online is out of date.

I eventually found Microsoft's documentation: [How to: Run Unit Tests in MTA mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404663.aspx)

You need to open your .testsettings file in an XML editor and add the following:

```
<TestSettings>
  <Execution>
    <!-- ... -->
    <ExecutionThread apartmentState="MTA" />
  </Execution>
</TestSettings>
```

Then restart Visual Studio. This worked for me.