# Visual Studio 2015: Run tests using MSTest in a Multi Threaded Apartment

Tags: visual-studio-2015, mstest, mta

I cannot find a way to do this for MSTest in Visual Studio 2015. How do you specify the apartment state to be MTA for all running tests?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730498/mstest-setting-apartment-threading-to-mta

Comment: @alexander-pacha: not really because that is not for 2015. There does not seem to be an easy way of getting a .testsettings file in 2015. I would obviously prefer a way that uses the .runsettings file.

Comment: But there is a way to get a TestSettings file. In the solution explorer right click on a project, then `Add... -> New Item... -> Test Settings / Test Settings`. And this file can be used in the menu: `Test -> Test Settings -> Select Test Settings File`

Comment: ! I was trying to add to the Project not the solution. Thanks that should help me get going.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comment above in the OP's question, you first need to add a test settings file.

*In the solution explorer right click on a project, then Add... -> New Item... -> Test Settings / Test Settings. And this file can be used in the menu: Test -> Test Settings -> Select Test Settings File*

Open this file using a text editor and add / edit the following value

```
<Execution>
    <ExecutionThread apartmentState="MTA" />
</Execution>
```

Your test settings file should now look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestSettings
  id="ba23bf15-d0c7-48fc-b300-6f04c3fbe665"
  name="TestSettings1"
  enableDefaultDataCollectors="false"
  xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
  <Description><!--_locID_text="Description1"-->These are default test settings for a local test run.</Description>
  <Deployment enabled="false" />
    <Execution>
        <ExecutionThread apartmentState="MTA" />
    </Execution>
</TestSettings>
```

Finally, restart Visual Studio.